# Create TextBox without a border in PHPWord

Tags: php, phpword

I'm trying to create a TextBox without a border in PHPWord, but setting `borderColor` or `borderSize` to `0` or `null` has no effect and I always get at least a black border around the text box.

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$textbox = $section->addTextBox(
    array(
        'alignment'   => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\Jc::END,
        'width'       => 200,
        'height'      => 40,
        'borderColor' => null,
        'borderSize'  => 0,
    )
);
$textbox->addText('dummy-text ...', null, array('alignment' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\Jc::END));
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord);
$objWriter->save('dummy.docx');
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a borderbox without border you can use ([git issue: no outline textbox](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/296)):

```
'borderSize' => 'none'
```

Tested and working with PhpWord 0.13.0 & opening the generated document with MsWord (libreoffice didn't seem to recognize this setting)

Comment: Well I found this before I asked but it did not work for me unfortunately. If I use code `$section->addTextBox(array('alignment'   => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\Jc::START, 'width' => 260, 'height' => 120, 'borderSize' => 'none'));` I end up with [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koHR6.png) in Word for Mac Version 15.30

Comment: This also does not work for me if I use `'borderColor' => 'none'` as suggested in the link by the way

Comment: As a temporary solution, I've set the `borderColor` to be the same as the background color of the document e.g. `'borderColor' => 'white'`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for an answer in PHPWord 0.17 following solution works:

```
'borderColor' => 'none'
```